# get() returned more than one -- it returned 2

Tags: django, python-2.7

Error:

```
 MultipleObjectsReturned at /fill/3e730d3858fbca620b1376f72e06473b227e5658/
 get() returned more than one survey_participant -- it returned 2!
 Request Method:    GET
 Request URL: *secret url cant share*
 Django Version:    1.8.4
 Exception Type:    MultipleObjectsReturned
 Exception Value:   
 get() returned more than one survey_participant -- it returned 2!
 Exception Location:    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 
  338
  Python Executable:    /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
  Python Version:   2.7.3
   Python Path: 
  ['.',
   '',
   '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.7.3-py2.7.egg',
   '/usr/lib/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']
    Server time:    Sat, 6 Feb 2021 23:47:07 +0530
```

survey/views.py: This is where the error is occurring, in line get_or_none. I'm getting two objects here.

```
def fill(request, link):
      fp = get_or_none(survey_participant, link__exact=link)

  if not fp:
    return render(request, 'survey/fill.html',
                 {'errormessage': constants.SURVEY_LINK_INVALID_TEXT})
```

What should I do now?

Comment: I think its obvious, there are 2 objects that have the same link. Check your db.

Comment: How can i fix that, so that I would take only one object.

Comment: check all objects in the db and see which 2 objects are the same the delete one.